# Scala external DSL - infinite loop caused by alternative repetitions

Tags: scala, grammar, dsl, parser-combinators

I am trying to build a simple external DSL in Scala that would be able to parse strings like:

```
value = "john${tom}peter${greg}${sue}meg"
```

In general, a substring within quotation marks contains interlaced names and names put between `${` and `}`.

My grammar is as following:

```
class Grammar extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def workflow = "value" ~> "=" ~> "\"" ~> pair <~ "\""

  def pair = rep(str | token)

  def str = rep(char)

  def char: Parser[String] = """[a-z]""".r

  def token = "$" ~> "{" ~> str <~ "}"
}
```

and executed by:

```
var res = parseAll(workflow, str)
println(res)
```

I thought that a method `def pair = rep(str | token)` would make it possible to parse it properly. Not only it doesn't work but also it leads to an infinite loop within `parseAll` method.

How can I parse such a string then? It seems that an alternative repetition (`rep`) is not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `rep` with `rep1`.

`rep` is always successful (unless it is an `Error`), so in `rep(char) | token` right part (`token`) is useless - you'll get an empty **successful** result of `rep(char)`.

Also, you could either replace `"""[a-z]""".r` with `accept('a' to 'z')` or define `str` as `def str: Parser[String] = """[a-z]+""".r`. Usage of `Regex` to match a single `Char` is an overkill.

Comment: I've missed that, thanks. Also, the usage of `Regex` here is an overkill of course, but I just wanted to share the same version of the code that caused a problem.